# Job failed to load: `@' is not allowed as an instance variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I keep getting error while using delayed job.

```
Job failed to load: `@' is not allowed as an instance variable name.
```

Calling it in here:

```
report = Report.find(params[:id])
report.delay.record_fixing( report.records.where(found: nil, pending: nil) )
redirect_to reports_path
```

And record fixing is

```
def record_fixing(records)
  records.search_fullcontact
end
```

Comment: paste code of method `search_fullcontact`

Comment: i am getting the same issue, have you got any solution to it?

Comment: and the full error trace.

Comment: @sevenseacat please check the answer, and comment.

Comment: is it still an issue ?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this issue here is the parameters that are being passed to the method `record_fixing` i.e.

```
   ActiveRelation Object(report.records.where(found: nil, pending: nil))
```

which gets serialized along with method name, as delayed job does this for some reason, and it fails to do so, hence raises this error,and adds it to table column `last_error`, so to fix such kind of issue i recommend that, we should pass object `id` instead of whole object, and fetch that object in the method `record_fixing`, the idea is to provide simpler arguments
for serialization.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy, what is your answer to it, please post.

Comment: @Abk, do you have anything to comment on this?